# How do I disable Google Chrome suggestions on sites like YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome

Here's the situation, the first two entries to be exact (second one brushed):

[image]

This does not seem to be related to autofill suggestions in the search bar, which are set to be off in my case - these keep popping up. I can't remove them via delete/shift delete, as suggested in another topic.

That's not a problem, since I can click dismiss, but I'd rather disable their appearance once and for all; it seems like Chrome saves some of my YouTube (and potentially other website) searches and then suggests them to me. Saved forms are off to me as well, emails/passwords etc. don't get saved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about Google Instant.
If you don't need any suggestions from Google, you can turn it off through settings.
Under Serach settings->Google Instant predictions-> click on Never Show instant results.

This will work out for sure.

Comment: My google instant search is not turned on in the first place.